# Unsafe call of an `any` typed value. Eslint with React native Async storage

Tags: react-native, eslint, typescript-eslint

I export functions of AsyncStorage to ease my development and write less and have all keys unform

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

export const _storeData = (key: string, value: string):Promise<void> => {
  return AsyncStorage.setItem(`@MyApp:${key}`, value);
};

export const _getData = (key: string):Promise<string | null> => {
  return AsyncStorage.getItem(`@MyApp:${key}`);
};

export const _removeData = (key: string): Promise<void> => {
  return AsyncStorage.removeItem(`@MyApp:${key}`);
};
```

Now when i try to use them i get error like:

Unsafe call of an `any` typed value.eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call

```
 async function logout() {
    await _removeData("User") ;
    setUser(null);
    setIsAuthenticated(false);
    await logoutRequest()
  }
```

So far this is where i get the error it does the same with _storeData and _getData, meaning none are working

My only option that worked is ignoring eslint there but I dont wanna do that for multiple reasons